# Data in datatable disappears when using pagination and requestscope

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces and Datatable with pagination. I have a request scope of the backing bean and when I browse through the datatable the data disappears (nothing to show). I thought the datatable was just Ajax that retrieved the whole list of data and hide parts of it? How can I fix this? Using sessionscope in the backing bean fix this, but I don't know ....

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JSF2 , you can put the bean that holds the databtable in the view scope. The beans in the view scope will keep alive  as long as you are staying on the same view.